# Multiple checkboxes Gutenberg control

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to create a similar Group Checkbox Control like the WordPress categories listing but have not been able to save my values. I am not convinced I am taking the best direction, but seem to be close to the answer.

[image]

I'd like these checkbox values to save to a single attribute as an array, but I am fine with saving the selections as a string (value1,value3,value4,etc).

Below is an example of the `edit()` method I have created and I've taken notes from a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653897/in-a-wordpress-gutenberg-block-how-can-i-create-a-multiple-checkboxes-using-a-ch), but am not able to get my selections to save:

```
attributes: {
    myCheckbox: {
        type: 'array',
        default: []
    }
},
edit: function ( props ) {
    var checkboxes = [];
    var data = [
        {
            label: 'Checkbox 1',
            value: 'checkbox1'
        },
        {
            label: 'Checkbox 2',
            value: 'checkbox2'
        }
    ];
    $.each( data, function ( c, fields ) {
        checkboxes.push(
            el( CheckboxControl, {
                key: fields.value,
                label: fields.label,
                name: 'myCheckbox[]',
                onChange: function( val ) {
                    props.setAttributes({ myCheckbox : myCheckbox[fields.value] });
                }
            })
        )
    });
    return [
        el(
            InspectorControls, {
                key: 'inspector'
            },
            el(
                PanelBody, {
                    title: __( 'Settings' )
                },
                checkboxes
            )
        ),
        el( ServerSideRender, {
            block: 'block/name',
            attributes: props.attributes
        } )
    ]
},
```

Comment: Instead of using a checkbox "value" you need to use the "checked" attribute. Also, you are creating two checkboxes that both update a single attribute called `myCheckbox`. You need to have a separate attribute for each checkbox. If the user can only choose one of the two, use radio buttons instead.

Comment: Thank you @WebElaine. I do have `checked` in the Checkbox control declaration, or are you talking about actually checking `myCheckbox.checked ? true : false` and if so, in the `setAttributes` function? I ask because I am still a little unclear, though your comment has given me a better understanding. By the way, I am not trying to create a radio, I only limited the choices to keep the example code shorter.

Comment: Yes, I meant checking `true : false` and using that in `props.setAttributes`. And, you need to have a separate attribute for each checkbox.

Comment: @WebElaine when you say separate attributes are you referring to something like `myCheckbox[fields.value]`? I am not sure how to reference `myCheckbox` as an array without getting errors.

Comment: Yes. You can either create a `mycheckbox1` attribute and a `mycheckbox2` attribute, or else if you are going to use a single `mycheckbox` attribute that is an array of values, you'll have to clone that array and update only the value that changed. Much simpler to use separate attributes IMHO.

Comment: I am trying to gather a list of selected items into one attribute so the date is easier to work with elsewhere - that's why an array makes the most sense. I've updated the post with further progress and I can now click the individual checkboxes and save, but when I come back the choices are deselected.

Comment: Anyone? Truly stuck and happy to send a tip at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
$.each(data, function (c, fields) {
  checkboxes.push(
    el( CheckboxControl, {
      key: fields.value,
      label: fields.label,
      name: 'myCheckbox[]',
      checked: props.attributes.myCheckbox.indexOf(fields.value) > -1,
      onChange: function( val ) {
        let data = props.attributes.myCheckbox;
        if (val) {
          if (data.indexOf(fields.value) === -1) {
            data.push(fields.value);
          }
        } else {
          data = props.attributes.myCheckbox.filter((v) => v !== fields.value);
        }
        props.setAttributes({ myCheckbox: data });
      }
    })
  )
})
```